# JS include URL as URL parameter

Tags: javascript

I have this script in JS which uses URL parameter for image location, it works fine when image is located in the same place as the script like below

```
<iframe src="pan.htm?image=img1.jpg" ></iframe>
```

But I need it to get the image from other location, how do I do it I tried the way below but it doesn't work this way (url is just an example)

```
<iframe src="pan.htm?image=http://someaddress.com/img1.jpg" ></iframe>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the url. You can do this by running this script:

```
prompt('Here is your completed code:',encodeURIComponent(prompt('Enter the url to encode','')));
```

You can try it out here: **http://jsfiddle.net/zenr8/**

The encoded URL that the script gives you is the thing you need to enter into the URL parameter. In your case, the iframe would look like this:

```
<iframe src="pan.htm?image=http%3A%2F%2Fsomeaddress.com%2Fimg1.jpg" ></iframe>
```

If you need to enter something in an URL parameter from a script, you should always make sure that it's properly encoded. You can do this by using `encodeURIComponent`. If you then need to decode it for further usage in your script, just use `decodeURIComponent` again. For example:

```
alert(encodeURIComponent('http://google.com/?hl=en&q=search'));
//alerts http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F%3Fhl%3Den%26q%3Dsearch
alert(decodeURIComponent('http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F%3Fhl%3Den%26q%3Dsearch'));
//alerts http://google.com/?hl=en&q=search
```

Comment: Thanks Guys this is what I needed, although there is also some kinde of corse support problem which should be resolved in the script I just have to fiddle around with it a bit to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to urlencode the parameter.

```
<iframe src="pan.htm?image=http%3A%2F%2Fsomeaddress.com%2Fimg1.jpg" ></iframe>
```

This could be done using php for example:

```
<iframe src="pan.htm?image=<?php echo urlencode("http://someaddress.com/img1.jpg"); ?>" ></iframe>
```

Or [with javascript itself](http://jsfiddle.net/ccatr/):

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src","pan.htm?image="+encodeURIComponent("http://someaddress.com/img1.jpg"));
var wrapper = document.getElementById("iframe_wrapper");
wrapper.appendChild(iframe);
```